# Python date converstion to quarters giving integer not Q1YYYY

Tags: python, date, time-series

I've having issues with converting dates as the output isn't giving me '2022Q4' but rather an integer 211. Tried a few different ways and just stuck! Tried using the index, formatting the index and then two ways i know of but can't get the result.

[image]

Code:

```
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
        df['Date'] = df.index.date
        
        df['Period1'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.index, freq='Q')
        df['Period2'] = df.index.to_period('Q')
        df['Period3'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q')
        
        df['Period4'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d')
        df['Period5'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Period4'], freq='Q')

        st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: i run your code and it works fine

Comment: I feel I've done this before without issue. It's quite annoying! Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you could use `to_period` do convert datetime data to period.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html

Comment: Hi, yes tried df.index.to_period('Q') but still get 211 not q42022 strangely.